# Php duplicate output in export

Tags: php, mysql, export-to-csv

I've had this problem for a while, I've posted this question here but I didn't have any feedback. I'm trying to export a query, i do it, it's just that the fields, they're duplicated. how can it be?

Here is the code:

```
$fh = fopen('hostess_query4.csv', 'w');
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT ".$username." FROM hostess");
if ( !$result1 ) { echo mysql_error(); }
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
    $last = end($row);
    foreach ($row as $item) {
        fputcsv($fh, $row, ',');
        if ($item != $last)
            fwrite($fh, "\t");
        }
    fwrite($fh, "\n");
    }
}

fclose($fh);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use mysql_fetch_assoc() instead of mysql_fetch_array.
Documentation:
http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array
http://php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc

Or use mysql_fetch_array with the second optional parameter set to MYSQL_ASSOC.

New code:

```
$fh = fopen('hostess_query4.csv', 'w');
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT ".$username." FROM hostess");
if ( !$result1 ) { echo mysql_error(); }
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
    $last = end($row);
    foreach ($row as $item) {
        fputcsv($fh, $row, ',');
        if ($item != $last)
            fwrite($fh, "\t");
        }
    fwrite($fh, "\n");
    }
}

fclose($fh);
```

Comment: Yes...you are getting duplicates because you are using mysql_fetch_array(). The foreach will loop through the entire result array (all numerical and alphabetical keys)

Comment: can you please tell me how my code should be in order to not get any duplicates... can you please update your answer with the code?

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing two separate approaches together.

The following approach would work. It uses [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to merge your rows.

```
$fh = fopen('hostess_query4.csv', 'w');

$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT ".$username." FROM hostess");

if ( !$result1 ) { echo mysql_error(); }

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
    fwrite($fh, implode(",", $row)."\n");
}

fclose($fh);
```

The reason for your issue is that mysql_fetch_array will return both 0 incremented and associative arrays. Example:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [ID] => 1
    [1] => Mike
    [NAME] => Mike
    [2] => 22
    [Age] => 22
)
```

So when you export that, it is exporting duplicates. Change it to mysql_fetch_assoc or mysql_fetch_object, and you will only have one set of values.

Comment: Can you provide the results in your question? Can we see what exactly is duplicated?

Comment: Sure, so, i do a query, in which i select the fields i need to extract, with this code you provided me, i get the result of this rows printed, just like they should but they are duplicated, something like [id][id][name][name]... this didn't happen when i would not insert that "," ...

Comment: No, still not doing anything..duplicating.. i don't know how this can be possible..

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
$last = end(mysql_fetch_array($result1)); // this will return the last element in $result1
while (list($username) = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {        
    fputcsv($fh, $username, ',');
    if ($username!= $last)
        fwrite($fh, "\t");
    }
    fwrite($fh, "\n");
}
```